# Unifying columns in the same Pandas dataframe to one column

Tags: pandas

Hi I would like to unify columns in the same dataframe to one column such as:

`col1  col2`
`1   1.4   1.5`
`2   2.3   2.6`
`3   3.6   6.7`

to 
  `col1&2`
`1   1.4`
`1   1.5`
`2   2.3`
`2   2.6`
`3   3.6`
`3   6.7`

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Use [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), then remove level by [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and last create one column `DataFrame` by [`to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_frame.html):

```
df = df.stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True).to_frame('col1&2')
print (df)
   col1&2
1     1.4
1     1.5
2     2.3
2     2.6
3     3.6
3     6.7
```

Or:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1&2': df.values.reshape(1,-1).ravel()}, index=np.repeat(df.index, 2))
print (df)
   col1&2
1     1.4
1     1.5
2     2.3
2     2.6
3     3.6
3     6.7
```